# Login error when user exists

Tags: php

I have a question about my login script.

I have made a login script using php which looks like this:

```
<?php 

include 'headermet.php';
include 'database.php';

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
    header("Location: /");
}

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username');
    $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';

    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];

        header("Location: /");

    } else {
        $message = 'ERROR while trying to login';
    }

endif;

?>

<body>

    <h1 style = "margin-top:100px;">LOGIN</h1>
        <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form action="login.php"= method="POST">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" name="username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" name="password">
        <input type="submit">

    </form>
</body>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```

In the code i added an error message if the credentials are not right. the message is `$message = 'ERROR while trying to login';` 
Using sequelpro i added a test user with the username : test and the password: test
[image]

when i fill the form with : test :test i get this: 
[image]

Comment: Well then do some debugging, to find out where it goes wrong ... Does `$results['password']` contain a value? Is `count($results)` actually greater zero? (Btw., you are trying to fetch a result row _before_ you’re doing this check - makes little sense.) What is the return value of `password_verify`? ... you know, the absolute basics of figuring out why does my script do what it does ...

Comment: your php code is ok. check your database table or database connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `password_verify` is new to me. Another way of doing it is if there is a match in the database you can assume that login was successful when rows are returned. Therefore:

First of all pass the password into the `SELECT` to check

```
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password');
```

Remember to bind the password as well

```
$records->bindParam(':password ', $_POST['password']); //Rather encrypt password
```

It is good practice to encrypt the password upon registration and then pass at login encrypt again for the password entered and in the database to match.

Then check if a row was returned

```
   $count = $records->rowCount(); // This will return the number of rows

    if($count > 0) //This will cause issue if more than one row is returned but illustrates the point.
    {
       $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
       header("Location: /");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First your login script is not secure u need to learn how to encrpt your password with md5 or others..  i prefe u use this and follow d steps

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) && $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']!=''){header("Location:home.php");}
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;hostdbhost', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword');/*Change The Credentials to connect to database.*/
$username=$_POST['username'];
 $password =(md5($_POST['pass']));  /*Encrpt your password with md5.*/
if(isset($_POST) && $username!='' && $password!=''){
 $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,username FROM tablename WHERE username=?");
 $sql->execute(array($username));
 while($r=$sql->fetch()){
  $p=$r['password'];
  $u=$r['username'];
 }

 if($p==$password){
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']=$id;
            $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $u;

  header("Location:home");
 }else{
  header("Location: login.php?error=1");
 } }
}

?>


 <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
       <span>Username<label>*</label></span>
      
    <input type="text" name="username" required> 
      </div>
      <div>
       <span>Password<label>*</label></span>
       <input type="password" name="pass" required>
      </div>
      
      <input type="submit" name="save" value="Login">
     </form>
```